# Firmware upgrade for iRobot Create 2

Tags: irobot-create

Is there a firmware upgrade for available for the Create 2? I had some issues in March when using these for assigning a University of Tennessee  programming project. We are getting ready to use them again (we have 10 now) and I'd like to get them all updated to the latest firmware.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, iRobot has found and fixed many firmware issues related to Create.   You should e-mail create@irobot.com for assistance.

Comment: Note: His profile clearly shows Ben's connection to iRobot :-)